# To scale the Coordinate axis using Group by in Python

Tags: python, pandas

My Y axis includes from 0 to 2.5 million.  Can I divide this number by 1000

How do I implement into this code?. My code is as follows.

```
df.groupby('CASE_STATUS')['Index'].nunique().plot(kind='bar',fontsize=12)
```

As you can see in the picture I want to divide the Y axis with a specific number

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o83Hs.png][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

isn't this enough to do the trick:

```
(df.groupby('CASE_STATUS')['Index'].nunique()/1000).plot(kind='bar',fontsize=12)
```